# Why is numpy.angle() not a ufunc?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

Why is `numpy.angle()` not a numpy universal function (ufunc)?

It seems to fit the criteria for a ufunc in the [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) but it's not listed as one.

I thought it might not fit the definition because it converts the type of the number (from complex to real), but there already are other ufuncs which do this (e.g. `np.absolute`).

I came across this because I was trying to apply `np.angle` directly to an xarray DataArray containing complex numbers, and it returns a numpy array instead of an xarray DataArray. I think it does that because it's not a numpy ufunc, and xarray checks for that.

Comment: Interesting.  Not every function that could be implemented as a ufunc is, and this seems to be one of them.

Comment: @user2699 I thought that might be the case - I'm going to submit an issue suggesting it be made one to numpy's github now.

Comment: Done here https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12961

Comment: Source code is available via the docs link.  It's python code, a thin wrapper around `arctan2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Full code for `np.angle` (from [numpy GitHub repo](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1408))

```
def angle(z, deg=0):
    if deg:
        fact = 180/pi
    else:
        fact = 1.0
    z = asarray(z)
    if (issubclass(z.dtype.type, _nx.complexfloating)):
        zimag = z.imag
        zreal = z.real
    else:
        zimag = 0
        zreal = z
    return arctan2(zimag, zreal) * fact
```

So it's a thin python wrapper for `np.arctan2`, which is a `ufunc`.

One guess is that no one has thought it needed to be a ufunc, or was interested in putting the work of casting it as such.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/c-api.ufunc.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/c-api.generalized-ufuncs.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html

It looks to me like it would a whole lot simpler to use `np.arctan2` directly, with your own thin wrapper for complex dtype array.

Comment: Thanks - I'm struggling to find where ufuncs are defined, once I find that I can see how hard this would be to add as a ufunc.

Comment: There are details in the `numpy` `c-api`.